# Broken behavior when checking "3D acceleration"

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 in a VirtualBox on a Windows 7 host. I have tried installing the Guest Additions both from the provided VirtualBox ISO as well as `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11`, but in both cases it boots/works fine when "Enable 3D Acceleration" is unchecked, but when I check it the display does not work correctly (toolbars and windows are invisible, etc.). Does anyone know how to fix this?